# How can I Adjust UTC/Local Time Zone

Tags: release-freya, time, networking

Because Windows uses local time as their base, I need to set elementary OS to also run in local time or it screws up my Windows 10 time setting and updates. How can I get elementary OS to run on local time instead of UTC?

Answer (score 3):

**Make Linux use 'Local' time**

To tell your System that the hardware clock is set to 'local' time:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/rcS
# change the following section

# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=no
```

elementary OS & Linux Mint are based on Ubuntu. So most commands from Ubuntu are also working on elementary OS & Mint.

Comment: Thank you pdunker, that is the command I was looking for.

Comment: @RockyBennett, if this answered solved your issue, be sure to mark it as accepted with the green check under the voting arrows

Answer (score 0):

Open "System Settings" and select "Date & Time"

**To use Network Time**

Select your time zone by clicking in the map or by clicking the button next to "time zone:" and selecting your time zone from the popover.

**To set the time manually**

At the bottom of the window, click the switch next to "network time". Set the date and time using the now-enabled text entry boxes